# httpRequest inside for loop sets same value for all records

Tags: parse-platform

I want to build and return an array of objects from CloudCode based on a query and the result of a httpRequest done for each record.

The problem with the following (example) is that it adds the same value for all "element" objects for all records. From testing I know that the variables "outside" the promises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(.. (e.g. "countryName") are unique.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

```
Parse.Cloud.define("search3", function(request, response) {

    var rs = [];
    var promises = [];

    // Query CountryTemp class
    var query = new Parse.Query('CountryTemp');
    query.limit(1000);
    query.exists("Country"); 
    query.include("Country");
    query.greaterThan('Month11', 25);

    query.find().then(function(results) {

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {

            var element = {};
            var result = results[i];
            var country = result.get("Country");

            var countryID = country.id;
            var countryName = country.get("Name");
            var temp = result.get("Month11");

            promises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                url: 'http://www.google.com'
            }).then(function(httpResponse){
                element.id = countryID;
                element.countryName = countryName;
                element.temp = result.get("Month11");
                element.httpresponse = httpResponse.text.substr(0, 50);
                rs.push(element);
            }));
        }

        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

    }).then(function() {
        response.success(rs);
    }, function() {
        response.error('error');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, Using underscore "_each" instead of "for" fixed it:

```
var _ = require('underscore'); 
..
_.each(results, function(result) {
```